# Como crear una lista de cookies desde flask

Tags: html, flask, cookies

Tengo una aplicación programada en flask y html y entre otras cosas, en la página tengo una serie de desplegables. Para los desplegables que son de selección única, he conseguido crear una cookie para que el valor seleccionado por el usuario se guarde. Sin embargo quiero hacer lo mismo para los desplegables que admiten multi-opción (select multiple='multiple') y no me funciona.

Muestro a continuación el código que me funciona para los desplegables de una única opción por si me podéis decir si hay alguna manera fácil de adaptarlo para los multiselección:

código flask:

```
@app.route('/pru/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def color():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.form)
        res = make_response("")
        res.set_cookie("prueba", request.form.get('prueba'), 60*60*24*15)
        res.headers['location'] = url_for('pru')
        return res, 302

return render_template('prueba_multiselect.html')
```

Código html:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="prueba" onchange="submit()">
        <option value="">----</option>
        <option value="Rojo" {% if request.cookies.get('prueba') == 'rojo' %}selected{% endif %}>rojo</option>
        <option value="Amarillo" {% if request.cookies.get('prueba') == 'Amarillo' %}selected{% endif %}>Amarillo</option>
        <option value="verde" {% if request.cookies.get('prueba') == 'verde' %}selected{% endif %}>verde</option>
    </select>
</form>
<h1>Hola esto es una prueba</h1>

<p>Hola2 esto es una prueba</p>

<p>Hola3- esto es una prueba</p>
```

Muchas gracias!